# Unable to unsquash from a firmware dump

Tags: firmware

after struggling for days I'm asking for help with this problem.

Link to download the [firmware](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d5uo5j841x30d0m/newdump.bin?dl=0).

I dumped a firmware image from an EEPROM Spansion FL128SAIF00 with flashrom and a buspirate via SPI in-system extraction. Binwalk shows the following:

```
kartone@kartone-VirtualBox:~/project$ binwalk -eM newdump.bin 

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
-----------------------------------------------------------------------   ---------
65536         0x10000         Broadcom 96345 firmware header, header size: 256, firmware version: "68", board id: "63168_FW_TW", ~CRC32 header checksum: 0x1FD327FA, ~CRC32 data checksum: 0xD3CB1AD5
1114112       0x110000        Squashfs filesystem, little endian, non-standard signature, version 4.0, compression:gzip, size: 7078804 bytes, 3030 inodes, blocksize: 65536 bytes, created: 2016-03-18 09:53:17
12189696      0xBA0000        Broadcom 96345 firmware header, header size: 256, firmware version: "68", board id: "63168_FW_TW", ~CRC32 header checksum: 0x968C91F8, ~CRC32 data checksum: 0x9965CD
13172736      0xC90000        Squashfs filesystem, little endian, non-standard signature, version 4.0, compression:gzip, size: 2847848 bytes, 1171 inodes, blocksize: 65536 bytes, created: 2013-12-04 12:31:36
```

So the extraction shows:

```
kartone@kartone-VirtualBox:~/project/_newdump.bin.extracted$ ll -R
.:
total 9,5M
drwxr-xr-x 3 kartone kartone 4,0K dic 12 22:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 kartone kartone 4,0K dic 12 22:21 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 kartone kartone 6,8M dic 12 22:03 110000.squashfs
-rw-r--r-- 1 kartone kartone 2,8M dic 12 22:03 C90000.squashfs
drwxr-xr-x 2 kartone kartone 4,0K dic 12 22:03 squashfs-root

./squashfs-root:
total 8,0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 kartone kartone 4,0K dic 12 22:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 kartone kartone 4,0K dic 12 22:03 ..
```

Binwalk is unable to extract those two squashfs filesystem:

```
kartone@kartone-VirtualBox:~/project/_newdump.bin.extracted$ binwalk 110000.squashfs 

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             Squashfs filesystem, little endian, non-standard signature, version 4.0, compression:gzip, size: 7078804 bytes, 3030 inodes, blocksize: 65536 bytes, created: 2016-03-18 09:53:17

kartone@kartone-VirtualBox:~/project/_newdump.bin.extracted$ binwalk C90000.squashfs 

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             Squashfs filesystem, little endian, non-standard signature, version 4.0, compression:gzip, size: 2847848 bytes, 1171 inodes, blocksize: 65536 bytes, created: 2013-12-04 12:31:36
```

So i tried to extract with these utilities (reported from evidence 11000.squashfs but same results of the second file C90000.squashfs)  :

```
kartone@kartone-VirtualBox:~/project/_newdump.bin.extracted$ unsquashfs -v; unsquashfs 110000.squashfs 
unsquashfs version 4.3 (2014/05/12)
copyright (C) 2014 Phillip Lougher <phillip@squashfs.org.uk>

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2,
or (at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.
Parallel unsquashfs: Using 2 processors
lzma uncompress failed with error code 9
read_block: failed to read block @0x6bea07
read_fragment_table: failed to read fragment table index
FATAL ERROR:failed to read fragment table


kartone@kartone-VirtualBox:~/project/_newdump.bin.extracted$ sasquatch -v; sasquatch 110000.squashfs 
unsquashfs version 4.3 (2014/05/12)
copyright (C) 2014 Phillip Lougher <phillip@squashfs.org.uk>

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2,
or (at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.
SquashFS version [4.0] / inode count [3030] suggests a SquashFS image of the same endianess
Non-standard SquashFS Magic: shsq
Parallel unsquashfs: Using 1 processor
Trying to decompress using default gzip decompressor...
Trying to decompress with lzma...
Trying to decompress with lzma-adaptive...
Trying to decompress with lzma-alt...
Trying to decompress with lzma-ddwrt...
Trying to decompress with lzo...
Trying to decompress with xz...
read_block: failed to read block @0x6bea07
read_fragment_table: failed to read fragment table index
FATAL ERROR:failed to read fragment table
```

Sadly same results with firmware-mod-kit extracting script:

```
kartone@kartone-VirtualBox:~/project/_newdump.bin.extracted$ sudo /opt/firmware-mod-kit/unsquashfs_all.sh 110000.squashfs 
Attempting to extract SquashFS 4.X file system...

Skipping squashfs-2.1-r2 (wrong version)...
Skipping squashfs-3.0 (wrong version)...
Skipping squashfs-3.0-lzma-damn-small-variant (wrong version)...
Skipping others/squashfs-2.0-nb4 (wrong version)...
Skipping others/squashfs-2.2-r2-7z (wrong version)...
Skipping others/squashfs-3.0-e2100 (wrong version)...
Skipping others/squashfs-3.2-r2 (wrong version)...
Skipping others/squashfs-3.2-r2-lzma (wrong version)...
Skipping others/squashfs-3.2-r2-lzma/squashfs3.2-r2/squashfs-tools (wrong version)...
Skipping others/squashfs-3.2-r2-hg612-lzma (wrong version)...
Skipping others/squashfs-3.2-r2-wnr1000 (wrong version)...
Skipping others/squashfs-3.2-r2-rtn12 (wrong version)...
Skipping others/squashfs-3.3 (wrong version)...
Skipping others/squashfs-3.3-lzma/squashfs3.3/squashfs-tools (wrong version)...
Skipping others/squashfs-3.3-grml-lzma/squashfs3.3/squashfs-tools (wrong version)...
Skipping others/squashfs-3.4-cisco (wrong version)...
Skipping others/squashfs-3.4-nb4 (wrong version)...
Skipping others/squashfs-hg55x-bin (wrong version)...
File extraction failed!
```

If useful, magic numbers of the file:

```
00000000  73 68 73 71 d6 0b 00 00  0d d0 eb 56 00 00 01 00  |shsq.......V....|
00000010  96 00 00 00 01 00 10 00  c0 06 01 00 04 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  af 02 97 59 00 00 00 00  94 03 6c 00 00 00 00 00  |...Y......l.....|
00000030  8c 03 6c 00 00 00 00 00  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  |..l.............|
00000040  70 1e 6b 00 00 00 00 00  05 79 6b 00 00 00 00 00  |p.k......yk.....|
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: are you able to share the firmware image?

Comment: Edited: added link to download the firmware dump.

Comment: I don't have time to dig into it right now but since the signatures are reported to be non-standard,  what you can try is comparing the first 128 bytes or so against the squashfs data in [this firmware binary](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h6zfzthwdzm6glz/Vx226x1_60200.sig?dl=0) as well compare the byte values with the [format specification](https://dr-emann.github.io/squashfs/). Vendors do seem to [do odd things](http://www.devttys0.com/2011/08/extracting-non-standard-squashfs-images/) with formats from time to time

Comment: @julian what firmware is this? Seems very similar to this I'm working on

Comment: It was shared on this site, but I cannot remember in which post, though. I believe it was for a Swisscom router. It may be from [this post](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8065/router-firmware-modification-and-mips-executable-under-x86-64-ubuntu-x-post-fro)

Comment: @julian i compared two squashfs blob but I got no clues about the failing extraction. Seems correct header information or if there's something weird I completely lost it. The only notable thing is that in the header I see gzip compression (and binwalk too) but unsquashfs and sasquatch utilities seem to recognize lzma compression.

Answer (score 4):

This problem was due to a corrupted dump: it turned out that dumping *in-system*, in some way, wakes up the main CPU that interfere with the eeprom on the SPI bus. Desoldering the chip and reading with the same tools, managed to give an extractable dump with Binwalk.

Comment: It’s great you were able to figure out what was causing the problem. Thanks for posting the answer here